# Access C++ ASCII Codes via Windows Terminal

Tags: c++, windows

Where could I find a complete list of ASCII codes that are compatible with C++? I want to use the Windows terminal to do so, as I know there is a way to do so with Linux (`showkey -a`).

https://linux.die.net/man/1/showkey gives more information for the Linux command, but I'm looking for a line or two that works for Windows.

Comment: Compatible with C++ in which way? Do you want a list of characters that are possible to use in a `.cpp` file? How is `showkey` related to C++?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking for which ASCII codes are compatible with C++? Or are you asking for how to find which ASCII codes the keys on your keyboard produce like `showkey -a` does on linux?

Comment: Compatible with C++ if I was testing which key the user pressed. The question I have is how to FIND the ASCII codes that my keyboard produces like `showkey -a` does in Linux.

Comment: So you want to implement some sort of  Windows port of `showkey`?

Comment: Your keyboard doesn't produce ASCII codes, unless you have a special keyboard that doesn't have function keys, arrows, Caps Lock, etc.

Comment: I want a line or two that I could type in to the Windows terminal that does the same as `showkey` in Linux.

Comment: Windows does not have a built-in program like `showkey`, even with PowerShell this task is more than just "a line or two". You are going to need to either make or find a program that works like `showkey`. Also addressing the "C++ compatibility" part of your question, ASCII is just a way of encoding characters in bytes, there is nothing stopping C++ from supporting *any* binary character encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not have a built-in program like `showkey` on Linux.

---

Since you're asking on a question tagged `c++` I thought I would write a quick c++ program that does what you're asking:

```cpp
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = _getch()) && (c != 3))
    std::cout << "Keycode: " << c << std::endl;
}
```

This will only compile for Windows because `conio.h` is a Windows header. You can exit with `Ctrl+Pause/Break`.

**Edit:** I made the program only 3 lines and added support for exiting with `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much!

Comment: Why `_getch()` and not `std::cin.get()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, `cin.get` (or `wcin` in `_O_U16TEXT` mode) reads from stdin via `ReadFile` (or `ReadConsoleW` if a console stream in UTF-16 mode), and it doesn't disable the console's echo-, line-, and processed-input modes. So what we type will be visible; we have to press enter after typing a character, which will be an LF in the stream; and some control characters will be processed (e.g. Ctrl+F will open the console's find dialog). `_getch` (or preferrably `_getwch`) does a low-level read directly from CONIN$ via `ReadConsoleInputW`, with the latter console input modes temporarily disabled.

Comment: @eryksun those are implementation details that may not be true in all implementations

Comment: @RemyLebeau, `get()` just reads a character from the stream. It's not specified to change underlying device settings on any platform or any type of device to implement a raw read that doesn't echo; wait for the user to press enter; or process control characters. You asked why we wouldn't use `cin.get`. That's why, and in particular for Windows C++ runtime, it's not just a generic reason, it's the way things are. I genuinely do not understand why you're pushing back against what I said.

Comment: @eryksun, thanks for answering with the specifics! I would have just said "because `cin` requires you to press enter."